# Bluemix CF command line can not push app project even though command line says successful

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

Im having trouble push my web application via Bluemix CF command line.

as you can see after downloaded the sample project I did a slight modification , I change the text body to "wow"
[image]

then I uploaded the project and its all successful,

however, when I click the app link from bluemix

http://javalibertybluemix.stage1.mybluemix.net/

the content of the app did not change at all.

its still the same.

Comment: Can you post in the logs from the cf push output or even better provide your sample app?

Comment: Hi James I know why it failed, because I did not build the project to generate new war file. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java project needs to be compiled using `ant`, which will generate an updated .war file. You need to push this war file. If you did a `cf push` from the root of the extracted project, cf will read the manifest.yml file and know to push the war file. See the README in the project for more details.

You can also import the project into Eclipse with Bluemix plugin and use Eclipse to compile and push.

Comment: thanks Ram, I used the "export" from Eclipse to generate the new war file, anyway it works. So bluemix basically did not upload the project and build it in cloud but run the war file from users right?

Comment: Right, `cf` pushed the project, but it does not to compile it. If you want Bluemix to compile your source, you can create a pipeline using Bluemix DevOps Services. You can create a DevOps project by clicking the Add Git button in your application dashbaord.